# Make /home/infinity/.Private larger

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm

I have already asked a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025330/activate-unused-hard-disks), but my question was poorly worded. Although heynnema wrote a good answer, it is not exactly what I was expected. So here is a new version better worded.

```
┌─╼ [~/grive]
└────╼ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for infinity: 
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CBF0E7EB-2677-4D68-B9B5-C9212D0CF17A

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 468860927 466311168 222.4G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x96196249

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9619624a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907026943 3907024896  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT




Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 222.4 GiB, 238749220864 bytes, 466307072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 154.4 GiB, 165767282688 bytes, 323764224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 67.9 GiB, 72926363648 bytes, 142434304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 67.9 GiB, 72925839360 bytes, 142433280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

┌─╼ [~/grive/Data_HFT/TnS]
└────╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        6.7G   11M  6.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  151G  114G   30G  80% /
tmpfs                         34G   27M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    705M  401M  253M  62% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        6.7G   16K  6.7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        6.7G   44K  6.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private      151G  114G   30G  80% /home/infinity
```

`sudo fdisk -l` made a list of all existing hard disks on my computer and `df -h` listed the hard disks use on my computer.

I wish to increase the memory of `/home/infinity/.Private` from `152G` to `151G + 1.9T + 1.9 = 3.951T`. I have two unused hard disks `/dev/sdb` and `dev/sdc`.

heynnema said in my previous question :

> if your final goal was to make your /.Private larger by adding two 2TB
>   disks to it, you should have said so earlier, 'cause that requires a
>   different approach. What does making /.Private=3.95TB any different
>   than using the disks mounted separately as you're doing now. If you
>   still want to do that, I'd recommend using LVM disks... but that's a
>   whole new question.

So how could I increase the global memory without losing information? I don't want to reinstall everything. If it is not possible to do it without reinstalling everything, how could I create another `home`?

I will explain  to you what would be the purpose of that new space. I need to store around 300GB of data for machine learning purpose so that I could use it locally.

Comment: We need more information about your environment.  Is `.private` a file container?  Is it a physical disk?  It *looks* to me like you have only 150GB of space for your entire system; how big is the hard drive in your computer?

Comment: Yes, I have approximately 150GB for my entire system. How could I know what is `.Private`. I know that I have encrypted my hard drive when I have installed Ubuntu 17.10.  When I opened it, it was just a serie of files and directories beginning by `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED`. I am really not an expert on hardware. Just tell me what you need and I will provide you quickly.

Comment: Note that by changing your question and asking 'What do you suggest" you've made the question an opinion-based-answer attractor, and those types of questions can be closed.

Comment: Your new question, by the way, would be 'answered' by following the suggestions in the 'similar' question that you link to - mount the drives at boot time, and then access the data via those two drives/partitions.

Comment: The two 2TB drives you mention, are they drives which are internal to the system or are they external USB drives or such?

Comment: No, they are internal.

Comment: First, you need to increase your partition size, not your memory, memory is RAM. Second, unless .private is on it's own partition, unlikely, you need to increase the size of the partition .private is on, likely /home or / . See https://askubuntu.com/questions/29866/increase-the-home-partition-without-losing-the-data . If you need to use more than 1 disc, then you need to use LVM. LVM is destructive, meaning you will loose your data. So you would then back up all of home, make your LVM, restore your data. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Each of those steps is likely a question of it's own and as .private is encrypted you have a significant risk of data loss or problems with encryption. I would almost suggest backin up ALL your data in your home directory and performing a fresh install with LVM and a large /home directory from the start. I would consider using LUKS (full encryption) rather than encrypting /home , but up to you.

Comment: LVM - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm or https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html or https://www.howtogeek.com/211937/how-to-use-lvm-on-ubuntu-for-easy-partition-resizing-and-snapshots/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This question was made a Community Wiki post because while this is technically my answer, I borrow off of others' answers, and do not deserve any reputation gains from this as a result.

**In theory**, you can build an LVM which will cover the entirety of the three disks, however we need a bit more information to determine if this is the proper route.  Namely, we need to know if the two 2TB disks you mention are internal drives or external hard drives.

If they're external hard drives, then the original answer from heynnema is valid and needs to be followed.

If they're internal drives, then in *theory* following the "Add another drive to your volume" part of [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7002/how-to-set-up-multiple-hard-drives-as-one-volume/7841#7841) by [Jacob Schoen](https://askubuntu.com/users/2488/jacob-schoen) would probably be waht you need to do:

> ### Adding another drive to your volume
>
> - So follow the steps in the first bullet again but for the new drive.
> - Now if the drive name is `/dev/sdb1` then do `sudo vgextend media /dev/sdb1` to add it to the volume.
> - Now we need to unmount the volume. To do this do `sudo umount /dev/media/volume`.
> - Now you can see the stats on your volume now by running `sudo vgdisplay`. The important part is `Free  PE / Size`. You need to know
>     how much space you can add to the volume for the next https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLgkr.jpg?s=64&g=1step.
> - So if you had 150 Gb of space you would do `sudo lvextend -L+150G /dev/media/volume`.
> - Now run `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/media/volume` to check the filesystem.
> - Now run `sudo resize2fs /dev/media/volume` to resize everything.
> - You can run the stats again and verify that `Free PE / Size` has dropped to what you expect.
> - Remount the volume by doing `sudo mount /dev/media/volume /mnt/media`
> - Rinse and repeat for any other drives.
>
> ---
>
> Also something that I found helpful was I had files I needed to copy off of disks to the LVM
>   I created before I added that disk. So I used `cp -r -v` so that it
>   would recursively copy files and use the verbose output so I know what
>   it was doing. An example of the full command would be:
>
> ```
> cp -r -v /mnt/temp/Movies /mnt/shared/media
> ```
>
> Where `/mnt/temp/Movies` is the folder you want to copy from.

Regardless of which method you choose, you should always back up your data before doing any system changes.

Comment: There was a comments thread/discussion on my original now-deleted answer; [that discussion is documented and continued in this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76101/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-ward-make-home-infinity-private-larger)

Comment: Nice answer. As the OP is using encryption I suggest backing up the users data as a first step.